# JSF navigation: from-action with args

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Sorry for my English. I have a `navigation-rule`:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/test/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{testMB.delete}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/test/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

`TestMB`:

```
public String delete(Test test){
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And `test.xhtml`:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{testMB.delete(testMB.instance)}">del</h:commandLink>
```

I click to `del` but rule is not working. If I use delete method without arg `Test test`:

```
public String delete(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

It is working. How to use with arg?

Comment: Is the `delete()` method itself invoked, when it is parameterized? Since you tagged [jsf-2.2], I do not doubt but are you running with EL 2.2 or higher? (It is a separate entity and not tightly coupled with JSF).

Comment: Method `delete(Test test)` is working. But `navigation-rule` is not working. It is working as `return null;`. I use jsf 2.2.1 from `org.glassfish`.

Comment: I did not try myself this explicit navigation with a parameterized action method but it may not be allowed to use a parameterized action method  that way  - `<from-action>#{testMB.delete}</from-action>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the question in jira of javaserverfaces. And I have the answer:

Please refer to the VDL documentation of `h:commandLink`. In there you'll see the requirements for type of the action attribute.

`javax.el.MethodExpression` (signature must match `java.lang.Object action()`)
You are trying to pass a method parameter where it is not supported.